# How to count the number of times a pattern changes?

Tags: r, regex, vector

I have a vector created simulating a continious time Markov Chain. The vector represents the path the chain may describe. Simulating 20 steps we could have:

```
 Xt <- c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0 ,0)
```

Further, the vector can jump 1 by 1 or jump from any state (5,4,3,2,1) to 0. So other simulation could be:

```
 Xt <- c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

I want to count the number of times the simulated chain jumps to other state (when the vector changes of number) within a determined interval. For example:

The number of jumps for the first vector I wrote for the first 10 elements is 2 (Jumps from 5 to 4 and 4 to 0). The number of jumps for the second vector I wrote for the last 10 elements is 0 (The last 10 elements are all 0)

So I would like to count the number of jumps (the number of times the pattern changes). I tried using `toString(Xt)`and then trying to match some regex but nothing worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `diff` for this which counts the difference between adjacent numbers in a vector.  Sum all instances not equal to zero to get total times the pattern changes.

First 10:

```
sum(diff(Xt[1:10])!=0)
[1] 2
```

Last 10:

```
sum(diff(Xt[(length(Xt)-10):length(Xt)])!=0)
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like just count the number of times the difference was not zero would deliver the desired result:

```
Xt <- c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0 ,0)
sum(diff(Xt) != 0)
```

If the goal was to write a function that takes a string and a starting positon it could be done thusly:

```
jump_in_next_10 <- function(string, start){ 
                                sum( diff(string[start:(start+9)]) != 0 )}

 jump_in_next_10(Xt, 3)
#[1] 2
```